# Does having athena query result have an impact to performance of services that uses it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, cost-management

I know that athena store every query results in the bucket and query data will just accumulate over time. I want to know whether retaining previous query results in S3 would make an impact to performance of my queries.

For background, I have AWS services(Glue and Lambda) that uses athena to return data and mostly my query results would change frequently. I noticed that there are 200GB worth of data in my S3 now. Currently, it has only archive configurations. I'm thinking of adding life cycle rule that will only retain worth 7 days or 30 days. Is query result really important to be in s3 if we are not really using it?

Answer (score 1):

Query results can be used for a limited amount of time by athena if you benefit  of [reuse query results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reusing-query-results.html) feature, or caching in AWS data wrangler library. For the remaining scenarios there is no impact on performances.
Query results older than few hours can be used just for auditing/debugging purpouses.
I definitely recommend to put a lifecycle rule to clean up objects older than x days, where x can be something like 3 or 7 days.
Doing so you will reduce s3 storage cost.

Answer (score 0):

These are two completely different things. Query results are stored in `S3` results location and the Glue Crawler runs over the Source Files. There is **NO** performance impact of having history of Query results.

Comment: so having life cycle to these stored results would not have any impact to athena or any services right? like in terms of querying?

Comment: nope, just S3 storage costs